# Passing a list as several arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, arguments

I'm trying to use a list as arguments, using the  :

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> print( *l )
```

I got an error :

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
t*
 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm using python 2.7 :

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.version
2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 13:56:14)
[GCC 4.7.2]
```

What am I missing ?
Thank you ! :)

Comment: We'll need some more context. The error you've posted doesn't match the code you've shown.

Comment: What's your actual use case?

Comment: Yes I'm sorry I have pasted the wrong error :

  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print( *l )

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `print` isn't a function in Python 2.7. To use the function instead of the statement in a given module, use a future statement:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

This needs to go at the top of your file, before any code that isn't a future statement (or the module docstring), because the compiler needs to see future statements first to compile the rest of the module differently based on the future statement.

Answer (score 2):

`print` is NOT a function in Python 2.7. It is a statement. So, you should do

```
print l           # [1, 2, 3]
```

If you want to use `print` as a function in Python 2.7, you should import `print_function` from `__future__`, like this

```
from __future__ import print_function
l = [1,2,3]
print(l)          # [1, 2, 3]
print(*l)         # 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `print` as a function then you have to use `__future__` or upgrade python to 3+

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are searching for?

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> def x(*args):
...     print args[0]
...     print args
>>> x(*l)
1
(1, 2, 3)
```

If yes, take also a look at [Arbitrary Argument Lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) in the Python documenation.